# Simple c++ member reference inside method (linker error after method resolved)

Tags: c++, class

All I want to do is create a getter for my `Rabbit::Color` property. I've done quite a bit of research I'd say now. My error reads: `'Rabbit::Color': function call missing argument list; use '&Rabbit::Color' to create a pointer to member` This lead to research on pointer to member readings that seemed way too complicated for what I wanted to do. Here's my method:

```
string Rabbit::getColor() {
string color = this->Color;
//return (color != "") ? color : "color has not been sent";
string test1 = "test";
return color;
}
```

The error occurs in my cpp file with the method. I'm coming from a c# background so maybe simply accessing a member from inside a method is more complicated than i thought..

Header:

```
public:
std::string Color();
int Age();
int ChildrenCount();

public:
string getColor();
int getAge();
int getChildrenCount();
```

My method is now as such:

```
string Rabbit::getColor() {
//return (this->Color() != "") ? this->Color() : "color has not been sent";
return this->Color();
}
```

And the new error is:  `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall Rabbit::Color(void)" (?Color@Rabbit@@QAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) referenced in function "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall Rabbit::getColor(void)" (?getColor@Rabbit@@QAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)`

Any ideas?? It only occurs when I use the `this->Color()` method. Thanks for the help so far guys.

Comment: Re. the update, the error is because you never provided a body for the function `std::string Color();`  .  You probably meant for `Color` to be a variable instead of a function. Please see the complete working example in Bill Lynch's answer.  And get a book to learn from, C++ is not well suited to trial and error learning. C++ doesn't have "properties".

Comment: Finally noticed. Feeling very small atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If you meant for this->Color to be a function...

`this->Color` is a function. We call functions by using parentheses. For example: `this->Color();`

#### If you meant for this->Color to be a member variable...

We declare member variables without parentheses. For example:

```
class Rabbit {
    public:
        std::string Color; // Notice the lack of parentheses because this is a
                           // member variable instead of a class method.
    ...
};
```

#### Here's a complete working example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Rabbit {
    public:
        Rabbit(std::string color, int age, int children);
        std::string getColor();
        int getAge();
        int getChildrenCount();

    private:
        std::string Color;
        int Age;
        int ChildrenCount;
};

Rabbit::Rabbit(std::string color, int age, int children):
    Color(color), Age(age), ChildrenCount(children) {}

std::string Rabbit::getColor() {
    return Color;
}

int Rabbit::getAge() {
    return Age;
}

int Rabbit::getChildrenCount() {
    return ChildrenCount;
}

int main() {
    Rabbit rabbit("blue", 5, 2);
    std::cout << "Color: " << rabbit.getColor() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Age:   " << rabbit.getAge() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Kids:  " << rabbit.getChildrenCount() << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Color: blue
Age:   5
Kids:  2
```

Comment: is dereferencing always a function?

Comment: Have you seen the edit? You're `this->Color();` syntax seems to be causing a linker error no matter how I use it in the method.

Comment: @gordlonious: Yes I have. I'm fairly sure that you need to read about how to declare methods and member variables in C++ classes. And maybe what the difference between the two are.

Comment: @gordlonious: Also, nobody wants to solve linker errors without seeing a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). It's a waste of everyone's time.